# How to See Ad without being tracked by Google and others?

Tags: website, privacy, web, blocking, adblock

I want to know how Google,Facebook,etc.. know I viewed AD? Are they know it by pixels(like in emails) on ADS or any other way?

Let Me Clear What I want to Know Take
Example-

**Here I Suppose UMatrix is only blocking element and no other addon/extension block AD**

Go on [Adblock tester](https://ads-blocker.com/testing/).
Now Suppose by-default UMatrix block everything from 3rd party.
And only allow

```
googleleads.g.doubleclick.net  - CSS and FRAME
pagead2.googlesyndication.com  - Script
```

Except this everything from 3rd party is blocked.
Now refresh page and Now you can see Google ADS.
I try to only allow ADS frames,Images,CSS in UMatrix as far as possible.

*Why*-
In reality **I want to support sites that runs due to ADS and also I don't want to be track across web**.So From above config of UMatrix I can see ADS but My Question is **How Google Know that I viewed  AD**. Because If I see Google ADS and Google think I blocked ads on sites because I blocked everything except above,then My seeing ADS doesn't worth the site and Google don't pay the site inspite of viewing ADS.

Comment: An advertisement is not just an image. There is some scripting behind it too. When you view the ad you also run the script, and it is this script that knows what's happening. It can be Javascript, serverside php scripting or a combination of both or something else. Also, just having ads on a site but not clicking them is not generating revenue to the AD space. It is actually the click that leads to the page of the ad and then purchasing something from that site that generates revenue for that AD. Google gets money becuase those that place ads pay google for the distribution of the ad.

Comment: First Thanks for your detail Answer and I have just little bit confusion please clear it. As you above say Click on ADS generate revenue not viewing it then why you say  "those that place ads pay google for the distribution of the ad.", if my thinking is correct then your meaning for distribution is to just distribute ad on sites. And Is it really no difference of using adblocker or not if I am not click and purchase from ADS ? Please clear my confusion

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Some ads have scripting to know if it is being viewed and by blocking ads, that is reduced, so sites get less revenue, but there are also situations where you have an affiliate link and its all about spreading the ad, and getting that click + sale afterwards.

Comment: Can you Please Write the your first answer in Answer box so that I close the issue and Mark as Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An advertisement is not just an image. There is some scripting behind it too.

When you view the ad you also run the script, and it is this script that knows what's happening. It can be Javascript, serverside php scripting or a combination of both or something else.

Also, just having ads on a site but not clicking them is not generating revenue to the AD space. It is actually the click that leads to the page of the ad and then purchasing something from that site that generates revenue for that AD.

Google gets money becuase those that place ads pay google for the distribution of the ad.

Some ads have scripting to know if it is being viewed and by blocking ads, that is reduced, so sites get less revenue, but there are also situations where you have an affiliate link and its all about spreading the ad, and getting that click + sale afterwards.